# How to set time for a timestamp in FTPClient

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

I have a file on a server and I want to modify its timestamp.

It seems the following line is for this purpose:

`ftpClient.mlistFile("file path").getTimestamp().setTime(date);`

But it does not change the date at all.

Here is the full code:

```
String remotePath = "/public_html/AX/dan.css";
Calendar ftpFile = ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath).getTimestamp();
Date date = ftpFile.getTime();
System.out.ptintln(date);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath).getTimestamp().setTime(cal.getTime());
System.out.ptintln(ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath).getTimestamp().getTime());
```

So the above code first print the old timestamp of the remote file, the modifies it to the current time and print it again. But if you run it you'll see that the second print is still the same as the old one. So action modification did not work.

Why is that? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setTimestamp()` instead of `setTime()`. According to the [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPFile.html#setTimestamp(java.util.Calendar)). Do something like this

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
FTPFile file = ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath);
file.setTimestamp(cal);
System.out.ptintln(file.getTimestamp());
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer I think it is half correct. `file.setTimestamp` only accepts calendar variables. so instead of `cal.getTime()`, I added `cal`. and it printed the correct date as I wanted. **BUT**, it seems it corrects the date for the instance file, and not the actual file. because `file` will have the new time, but the actual file in the server still holds the old time. This line can prove it: `System.out.ptintln(ftpClient.mlistFile(remotePath).getTimestamp().getTime());` Do you know why this happens ?

Comment: Sorry man I must've missed that part in hurry. Edited. Now, I'm not really sure why the actual file is still holding old time. Have you tried flushing? On another thought, properties like last update timestamp highly dependent on filesytem and OS. Sometimes you cannot even change a file's last modified time with a Java program like I just checked in ubuntu last modified time only changes when I write something to a file and then flush it. Only open and close doesn't change it. So it can be something with how lower level systems are handling your files. Sort of wild guess but worth considering.

Comment: Can you tell me why you are trying to change the last modified time? There can be a better solution to the problem you are actually trying to solve rather than trying in this way.

Comment: Well, I am creating a software that syncs a set of local files with the remote file. so if the file doesn exist on the server, it copies the file, and sets its last modified date the same as the local file. Therefore, the second sync will have a logic to decide ether override the file or keep it as a latest version. The is why I need last modified. And I noticed `modificationTime` and `TimeStamp().getTime()` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setModificationTime()` on the `FTPClient`.

According to this [link](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-example-get-and-set-file-modification-time), it takes a date as a string in the format:

> yyyyMMddHHmmss

Here's a snippet:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
ftp.setModificationTime(fileName, sdf.format(new Date(localFile.lastModified())));
```

Running `setTimestamp()` on the `FTPFile` didn't work for me either. In fact, the server doesn't receive any command related to it, so it either requires another step or it's not meant for this purpose.